# XML Deserialization results in empty object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm attempting to deserialize this XML file into an object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rules version="3">
  <emie>
    <domain>msdn.microsoft.com</domain>
    <domain exclude="false">
      bing.com
      <path exclude="true">images</path>
    </domain>
    <domain exclude="true">
      news.msn.com
      <path exclude="false">pop-culture</path>
    </domain>
    <domain>timecard</domain>
    <domain>tar</domain>
  </emie>
</rules>
```

I have my objects laid out like so

```
[XmlRoot("rules")]
public class Rules {
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("emie")]
    public EMIE EMIE { get; set; }
}

public class EMIE {
    [XmlArrayItem("Domain")]
    public List<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}

public class Domain {
    [XmlAttribute("exclude")]
    public bool Exclude { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem("Path")]
    public List<Path> Paths { get; set; }
}

public class Path {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool Exclude { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And am using this code to deserialize it

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rules));

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("EM.xml", FileMode.Open)) {
            Rules xml = (Rules)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            foreach (Domain d in xml.EMIE.Domains) {
                Console.WriteLine(d.Value);
                foreach (EnterpriseModeModel.Path p in d.Paths) {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

However, my `rules.EMIE.Domains` object is always empty. When I debug I can see my `stream` object has a length so it's properly picking up the data in the file but it never fills up the object like I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the declaration of  `EMIE` as follows

```
public class EMIE
{
    [XmlElement("domain")]
    public List<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, good call I read somewhere you had to specify it as an [XmlArrayItem("name")]. But this worked. Thanks!

Comment: @L.B can you please explain briefly as to why this worked? Will the attribute on List<Path> Paths { get; set; } have to be changed to XmlElement as well?